# If the original variable is missing from the class containing the referenced member, why is it still accessible?

Tags: c++

A member of a class is a reference to a local variable. When the local variable is destructed, and the object of this class still exists, you can access the destructed local variable through this object. Why?

```
  #include <stdio.h>   
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class c2
    {
    public:
        int& a;

        c2(int & c):a(c)
        {
        }
    };
    int main()
    {

        c2 * p;
        {
            int i = 20;
            p = new c2(i);
        }
        cout << p->a;


        system("pause");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That's just the way it is.  Don't pass references to stuff that will prematurely go out of scope.

What happens is undefined behavior, it could be anything.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. [Nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) is another.

Comment: It's just plain machine voodoo.

Comment: @zhangkai - Please also read the answer to [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by some comments above, the behavior is actually undefined. See in particular the c++ reference on the [Lifetime of a temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary):

> a temporary bound to a reference in the initializer used in a
>   new-expression exists until the end of the full expression containing
>   that new-expression, not as long as the initialized object. If the
>   initialized object outlives the full expression, its reference member
>   becomes a dangling reference.

If you use `gcc` or `clang` you can compile the program with the option `-fsanitize=address`: it will crash with

```
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope
```

Instead, you will not get any error if you modify your program as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>   
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class c2
    {
    public:
        int& a;

        c2(int & c):a(c)
        {
        }
    };
    int main()
    {

        c2 * p;
    {
      int i = 20;
      p = new c2(i);
      cout << p->a;
    }
    delete p;

        return 0;
    }
```

(In the program I have inserted a `delete p` to avoid memory leak)